# Увеличение двумерного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не понимаю как реализовать функцию, которая должна принимать двумерный список строк и увеличивает его в два раза, то есть удваивает каждый символ по горизонтали и вертикали. У меня получилось следующее:

```
list_arr = [[]]
list_arr3 = ['']
list_arr1 = ['@']
list_arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def enlarge(list_arr):
    list_arr = [list_arr for _ in range(len(list_arr))]
    return list_arr


print(enlarge(list_arr))
print(enlarge(list_arr1))
print(enlarge(list_arr2))
print(enlarge(list_arr3))
```

Выводит следующее:
[image: Вывод]

Comment: Приведите пример ожидаемого ответа. Потому как ваше " удваивает каждый символ по горизонтали и вертикали" -  абсолютно непонятен.

Comment: `которая должна принимать двумерный список строк` тогда почему у вас используется массив и числа?

Comment: Должно быть что-то типа этого list_arr = ['@'] # => @@ 
                                                                             # => @@

Comment: print(['@'] * 2)

Comment: Это будет увеличение в 4 раза, а не в два.